# How to peek at object on the bottom of a stack?

Tags: c#, stack

I'm writing a ActionScript ByteCode parser in an the specs say to obtain the object at the bottom of the stack. Now as far as I can tell the bottom of the stack in the ActionScript Virtual Machine (AVM) is the object that was pushed first onto the stack. I'd really like to avoid popping all the items off the stack just to get to the bottom. Does anyone know if obtaining the bottom item is possible? If not, its some freaky stuff the AVM does :P

Thanks, Josh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is against the purpose of stack. However you can write a wrapper class.

When Push method called and the stack is empty add it object to stack and also keep a reference in your class. When Pop method called and the stack has only one object clear reference you keep.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible by definition. Each elements of stack know only about element before him, so with clasic stack implementation you don`t know address of the bottom element from the stack.
Use another structore to store objects. (List, for example)

Comment: Alright, I was trying to avoid using a different type as a Stack is exactly what is needed here.

Comment: You could make your own wrapper around a stack and store the bottom item within your wrapper...

Answer (score 1):

You can use ToArray().

```
var stackArray = myStack.ToArray();
```

And then just:

```
stackArray.Lenght - 1
```

to access the last element.